# ASP.NET Core 7 MVC - Load Views with Page directive from database

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a dynamic application that has all the views stored in a database as opposed to the file system. This works really well and is seamless from having physical files. I implemented a custom `IFileProvider` and then registered it using the following code.

```
builder.Services
       .AddControllersWithViews()
       .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(opts =>
            {
                 opts.FileProviders.Clear();
                 opts.FileProviders.Add(new ViewFileProvider(configuration));
            });
```

The problem I am having now, is that when I create a view and try and use the `@page` directive, it does not resolve?

I then went and physically added a `Pages` folder and placed an `index.cshtml` file in there with a `@page "/flow/login"` directive at the top, and now I can navigate to the path as specified without any issues.

So to the question is: how do I configure the application to use my custom `ViewFileProvider` to resolve views that have a `@page` directive?

I do have a call to

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options => {
   options.RootDirectory = "/Pages";
});
```

and then

```
app.MapRazorPages();
```

later, but this seems to have no effect. When I put breakpoints in my custom `IFileProvider` I can see that it never gets hit? Does the compiler maybe set up some custom routing at compile time that I don't know about?

Comment: I see you post another question: [reate a Razor View at runtime from string content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77262603/create-a-razor-view-at-runtime-from-string-content). Is your this problem soved ?

Comment: @QingGuo - Unfortunately not, that post is unrelated. I still have not resolved this issue. It seems that when the app starts it scans the "Physical file system" and then compiles and adds routes for the Razor Pages it finds. I would like to do this at runtime ( a CMS system )

Comment: @MarkRedfern  - I encountered a similar issue recently. I'm curious, were you able to find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not @samet B. I wish I could because using pages as opposed to views is much more flexible in terms of handling postbacks etc